# How to eliminate Duplicate documents from Document List in Webmethods?

Tags: webmethods

I have input document list containing AccountID and Amount fields which has repeated AccountID's but with different Amount. How can i form the ouput doclist with only unique AccountID's but the amount summed up?

Ex: InputDocList
Doc[0]: AccountID = 111
        Amount = 100

Doc[1]: AccountID = 222
        Amount = 200

Doc[2]: AccountID = 111
        Amount = 300

Doc[3]: AccountID = 222
        Amount = 500

OutputDocList should look like:
Doc[0]: AccountID = 111
        Amount = 400

Doc[1]: AccountID = 222
        Amount = 700

Answer (score 3):

I would group the documents by AccountID using `pub.document:groupDocuments`.  This will give you a group for each unique account ID.

Then for each group, use `pub.math:addInt/FloatList` to sum the amounts, and map the result to a new list of *{AccountID,totalAmount}* documents.